# Make ggplots of each column with loop and save as pdf

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have 149 series that I would like to plot as a line plot (year as x-axis) and these should be automatically generated in a pdf, ideally 4 plots on one page. Currently I can only do it with the normal plot function, is it also possible with ggplot?
So it works fine with normal plots:

```
dfMA <- structure(list(year = c(2000:2005),a = c(0.2569, 0.0145896,
0.0369, 0.025986, 0.12569, 
                           0.3695), b = c(0.125, 0.04582, 0.2569, 0.256369, 0.25698, 0.1456
                           ), c = c(0.2584, 0.05698, 0.1258, 0.2569, 0.098563, 0.1569)), row.names = c(NA,-6L), class = "data.frame")


pdf("test.pdf")
par(mfrow=c(2,2))

invisible(lapply(colnames(dfMA),function(x){
  plot(dfMA$year, dfMA[,x],main=x,type="l",xaxt="n", ylab = "Ring width [mm]", xlab = "", ylim=c(0,0.8)) + grid(nx = NULL, ny = NULL,lty = 2, col = "gray", lwd = 2) + axis(1, at = seq(1985, 2019, by = 2), las=2)
}))

dev.off()
```

Unfortunately, when I try to adapt the invisible function to ggplot, it doesn't work.

```
invisible(lapply(colnames(dfMA),function(x){
  ggplot(dfMA, aes(x=i, y = year)) + ggarrange(ncol=2,nrow=2) + geom_line() + print() 
         }))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need for `invisible`. Additionally, you first have to create your plots and store them in a list before you could glue them together using `ggarrange`. Finally I used the `.data` pronoun to map the column names (which are character strings) on the `y`aesthetic:

```
library(ggpubr)

pdf("test.pdf")
plots <- lapply(colnames(dfMA), function(x) {
  ggplot(dfMA, aes(x = year, y = .data[[x]])) +
    geom_line() +
    scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 0.8)) +
    labs(y = "Ring width [mm]", title = x)
})
ggarrange(plotlist = plots, ncol = 2, nrow = 2) 
dev.off()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here is a `tidyverse` approach:

```
library(tidyverse)

plots <- dfMA %>% 
  pivot_longer(-year, names_to = "variable", values_to = "value") %>% 
  group_by(variable) %>% 
  nest() %>% 
  mutate(plot = map(data, ~ggplot(.x, aes(x = year, y = value)) +
                      geom_line() +
                      ylab("Ring width [mm]") +
                      xlab("Year") +
                      scale_x_continuous(limits = c(2000, 2005), breaks = seq(2000, 2005, 1), expand = c(0, 0)) +
                      scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 0.8), breaks = seq(0, 0.8, 0.1), expand = c(0, 0)) +
                      ggtitle(""))) %>% 
  pull(plot)

# Save the plots
pdf("plots.pdf", width = 8.5, height = 11)
gridExtra::grid.arrange(grobs = plots, ncol = 2, nrow = 2)
dev.off()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

One which I do using `ggsave`

Try this

```
   library(ggplot2)
    
    for (col in colnames(dfMA)[-1]) {
      p <- ggplot(dfMA, aes(x = year, y = get(col))) + 
        geom_line() + 
        labs(title = col)

  
  ggsave(paste0(col, ".pdf"), p, device = "pdf")
}
```